# Convergence of integrals by examining the sum

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, indefinite-integrals

I am just looking for someone to tell me if my reasoning is correct. Let's look at the integral:
$$\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{x^a}{x + 1}dx$$
where $a$ is a real number. Is it valid to say that the integral will converge when the sum converges:
$$ \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{x^a}{x + 1}dx \sim \sum^{\infty}_{n = 0} \frac{n^a}{n + 1}$$
So:

- for $a < 0$ the first term is undefined
- for $a=0$ the sum diverges
- for $a>1$ the sum diverges
- for $0<a<1$ the sum converges

Is it valid to conclude that the integral converges only for $0<a<1$? Does this reasoning work for other integrals of this type, is there something I should pay attention to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not a valid method in general, for the convergence we need to show that for some convergent $\sum a_n$

$$0\le \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{x^a}{x + 1}dx \le\sum^{\infty}_{n = 0} a_n$$

As an alternative note that for $a\ge0$

$$\frac{x^a}{x + 1}\sim x^{a-1}=\frac1{x^{1-a}}$$

and for $a<0$ let $b=-a>0$

$$\frac{x^a}{x + 1}=\frac{1}{x^b(x + 1)}$$

and

- as $x\to 0^+ \implies \frac{1}{x^b(x + 1)} \sim \frac1{x^b}$
- as $x\to \infty \implies \frac{1}{x^b(x + 1)} \sim \frac1{x^{b+1}}$

then refer to limit comparison test to conclude that the given integral converges for $a\in(-1,0)$.

Comment: I am somewhat conflicted, I do understand that I would have a hyperharmonic series for negative $a$ but the first term troubles me. Any insight on that?

Comment: @user1949350 You could simply discard it, since the convergence is only related to terms with sufficiently large indices.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't worded it properly. Let's say I choose $a=-1$, then I would have(for $n=0$): $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{0} $$

Comment: @user1949350 for a negative let $a=-b$ we have that at $x \to 0$ $$\frac{x^a}{x + 1} =\frac{1}{x^b(x + 1)} \sim \frac1{x^b}$$ which converges for $0<b<1$ and at $x\to \infty$  $$\frac{x^a}{x + 1}=\frac{1}{x^b(x + 1)}\sim \frac1{x^{b+1}}$$  which converges for any $b$.

Comment: So in order for it to converge for all $x>0$ I need $$-1<a<0$$?

Comment: @user1949350 I aree with suggestion given by xbh, in that case your are selecting a series for the comparison test and you can always discard some term. The important point is that the inequality holds to prove the convergence.

Comment: @user1949350 Yes exactly the given integral converges for $a\in(-1,0)$.

Comment: @user1949350 I've updated the answer with all the details given in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot assert that the integral converges for $0 < a < 1$. Using *comparison test* you would notice that 
$$
\frac {x^a}{1+x} \sim \frac 1{x^{1-a}} \quad [n \to \infty], 
$$
and $\int_A^\infty (1/ x^p) \mathrm dx \;[A>0]$ converges iff $p > 1$. Hence the integral converges when and only when $\color{red}{a < 0}$ [WRONG HERE, see UPDATE 2].

Meanwhile, the series is also diverges by similar testing method.

---

There is a test for convergence of series: [integral test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). However this requires the function be *decreasing*. So *generally* you cannot use the correspondent series to test the convergence for this kind of improper integrals [although I do not know the counterexample when $f$ is not decreasing. Any comments about this are welcome].

UPDATE

Thanks to @RobertIsrael, the integral test is applicable to your question since $f(x) = x^a /(x+1)$ is monotonic for sufficiently large $x$.

UPDATE 2

I was wrong in the comparison test above. When $a < 0$, the point $0$ would also be questionable. Combining the asymptotic behavior as $x \to 0^+$ and $x \to +\infty$, the conclusion should be: the integral converges iff $\boldsymbol {0 < a < 1}$.

Comment: Although it's not decreasing on all of $(0,\infty)$, it is either decreasing for sufficiently large $x$ or increasing for sufficiently large $x$, and that's enough to allow the Integral Test to be used.

Comment: +1 but I don't like the idea you commented to simply discard the term. I cannot wrap my mind around the idea that if one term is undefined the sum can converge.

Comment: @user1949350 Then you could probably use other method, since this one does not work.